CMake error: Cannot find python executable
I had a CMake file which searches for a python executable as
find_program(PYTHON python)
if(NOT PYTHON)
    if(MSVC)
        set(PYTHON "python3.12")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "could not find python executable")
    endif()
endif()
get_filename_component(PYTHON_PATH "${PYTHON}" DIRECTORY)

while generating cmake cache for the above script I get an error in build logs
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:/Users/himanshu/CMCommon/index_common.cmake:545 (message):
  could not find python executable      C:/Usershimanshu/CMCommon/index_common.cmake    545

I see the python executable is present in my environment variable as well.

How can I debug the above error?
EDIT: Posting the error that I got after executing the cmake command given by OrenishShalom
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

If I type just the cmake command in shell, it works fine but I don't know why it gives above error.

just to make sure I understand - the MSVC part is actually irrelevant (right?) what bothers you is that cmake doesn't find python ?

I would create a minimal example just for the sake of finding python:
$ type .\CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(Project)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
find_program(PYTHON python)
cmake_print_variables(PYTHON)

Then run it to make sure it works:
$ cmake . | Select-String -Pattern 'PYTHON' -CaseSensitive

-- PYTHON="C:/Users/tuna_/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe"

If you run the same thing it will be easier to help you

This is not really an answer, and will be extended based on the results from the OP

How do I run that cmake command outside visual studio?

just open a power shell

I get error after executing the command you gave, I have posted error in EDITS.

can you try to run the above CMakeLists.txt from VS command prompt ?
